# React Native missing pixels, when we put some separator or border in Flatlist separator or in map method for executing mutiple JSX items

Tags: react-native, layout, separator, flatlist

In my React Native Project, I am trying to make some kind of lists using **Flatlist** or sometimes **using map method**, for executing JSX Element. I am getting the result correctly, But there is a bit of a problem in separate.

Let's take chatting app example, When we open WhatsApp there are a lot of people showing up, but there is also a tiny separator after each item, That looks great, Now exactly when I try to put that separator in my React Native application using **ItemSeparatorComponent** attribute in Flatlist, It's working but still in some places, meaning in some items that separator not showing up, its looks missing, it feels that there is no border/separator. And actually what's going on is that, the below item from that separator which is hidden or which height looks smaller than others, that below View go a little bit towards the upside, so the separator gets to hide, That's the main problem, Why is that happening, I tried everything but still, I am getting that UI problem.

Here is code example:

```
<FlatList
  data={actionSheet._data}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  keyExtractor={(_, index) => index}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => <ActionSheetClickableItem data={item} index={index}/> }
  ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
    <View
      style={{
        height: 1,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

***OR***

```
<ScrollView>
  {
    actionSheet._data.map((item, index) => (
      <>
       <ActionSheetClickableItem data={item} index={index} key={index}/>
       <View
         style={{
           height: 1,
           width: '100%',
           backgroundColor: 'red'
         }}
       />
      </>
    ))
  }
</ScrollView>
```

So according to the above code, I know for sure, that everything is correct, But why is that separator get hidden, If we look at this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRJ4c.png) in the area of the green rectangles, there is no border showing up, Why... I want to show it here, I tried to put **zIndex** property, that trick working correctly but that isn't the solution, It have to correct view as we expecting, why its behave like this, any solution??????

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.

That might be with Emulator or Your screen.
You can use also increase the height of itemSeparater or make the background color more darker.

If you check it in real device then it displays all the separaters.

Comment: Yea as you said in read device it work but only in iOS but still its happening with real android device, i checked this issue over 20 real devices... in some device somewhere border show missed or little hidden but all device have different borders effect... I also update my project with latest react native but still its the same... Hope in future react native note this issue